# Angularjs custom route with not mandatory value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to create a state route with AngularJS with a not mandatory portion of url.

```
.state('ProfileCtrl', {
            url: "/profile/{id_user}**/{not_mandatory}**"
      })
```

The route must be valid for both following urls

/profile/123123123

/profile/123123123/photo

/profile/123123123/video

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found

```
.state('ProfileCtrl', {
        url: "/profile/{id_user}{action:(?:/[^/]+)?}"
  })
```

Comment: you can also have additional state too.. (just in case too much conditional changes)